# Having an Issue in restricting length of password

Tags: 10.04, ssh, security, password

I am trying to place a restriction on my **ssh** box to require a password of a min. length of 16 character and a max. of 30.

I was following the Password policy section, in the official [user documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/user-management.html) and set the following in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure min=16 max=30 sha512
```

However when I turn on **ssh**, as a regular user, and go to change my password via *`passwd`*, I am restricted to a minimum of only **8** characters.

Would anyone have any ideas as to why the min. of **16** is not being recognised or it was something I have overlooked?

OS is Ubuntu Server 10.04.

Comment: Take a look at this question too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180402/how-to-set-a-short-password-on-ubuntu/180431#180431 It seems somehow related.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old but for in order to help others here's what I've found.

`minlen` is not just a basic character length restrictor, it it more a *score* that takes a number of criteria into account

[source](http://sattia.blogspot.ie/2012/05/how-to-enforce-password-complexity-on.html):

> The minlen complexity measure is calculated in a number of steps:
>
> - every character in a password yields one point, regardless of the    type of character
> - every lowercase letter adds one point, but only up to the value of `lcredit`
> - every uppercase letter adds one point, but only up to the value of `ucredit`
> - every digit adds one point, but only up to the value of `dcredit`
> - every special character adds one point, but only up to the value of `ocredit`

What I was seeing was a `minlen` of *16* allowing passwords of *8* characters as I was getting 2 points per character typed.

This is also documented in `man 8 pam_cracklib`:

> The minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if credits are not disabled which is the
>    default). In addition to the number of characters in the new password, credit (of +1 in length) is given
>    for each different kind of character (other, upper, lower and digit). The default for this parameter is 9
>    which is good for a old style UNIX password all of the same type of character but may be too low to
>    exploit the added security of a md5 system. Note that there is a pair of length limits in Cracklib
>    itself, a "way too short" limit of 4 which is hard coded in and a defined limit (6) that will be checked
>    without reference to minlen. If you want to allow passwords as short as 5 characters you should not use
>    this module.

Comment: I doubt that is the case. Have you tried rebooting the machine and then see what happens when you attempt to change the password?