# How to set a short password on Ubuntu?

Tags: password

When I install the Ubuntu, I set a short password(<4). Now I want to change the other short password by "passwd" or change passphrase on "Password and Keys" program, it needs a password >4 char.

Comment: Why do u want to set a short password? That is not safe, try you change the password from root account even if you forced to do.

Comment: @karthick87 because my home computer is not Fort Knox. If strangers are messing with my desktop then I have bigger concerns than my computer.

Comment: @karthick87 Why a short password? Ubuntu might run as a virtual machine and your virtualization software lacks copy and paste functionality for the command line of Linux guests (like Parallels desktop for Mac 8.0 does miss), then you want to access Ubuntu with a short password, or even better without a password at all.

Comment: @karthick87 Fixing the parameters of what a password should be like, makes a password easier to guess and therefore less secure.

Comment: Why short ? My password has 1,4 GB ! - It is fun !

Comment: My hard drive is encrypted and account passwords do nothing against physical access anyway. Maybe privilege escalation by running software is a valid fear, but I think retry-limits should largely protect against that.

Answer (score 280):

Use following command in Terminal:

```
sudo passwd <user>
```

Replace `<user>` with the username whose password you wish to change.

This works because `passwd` suppresses all checks for length or entropy when you use it as the root user.

> **Warning:** if the target user has an **encrypted home directory**, this will
>   cause problems!
>   ([see comments below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180402/how-to-set-a-short-password-on-ubuntu#comment522410_180428))

Comment: This does not work. It does not provide the information required.

Comment: It does work. If you are root it will not force you to fallow the password strength requirements.

Comment: This works fine for me. I'm able to set a user's password to `a` using this method, on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system.

Comment: This works for me too and is a much simpler solution. Ubuntu 12.10, Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: On 12.04 I get the message `passwd: user 'username' does not exist`. I'm sure I entered user name correctly.

Comment: This will cause problems when you have an encrypted home directory, as it breaks the automatic decryption of the `ecryptfs` passphrase.

Comment: @guntbert is right: Forcing the password this way the user won't be able to login again if his/her home directory is encrypted, so this is not the right solution in these cases.

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't update the gnome keyring, which leads to an error like "The password for the gnome keyring is not the same as the login password."

Comment: interestingly enough, when you call `passwd`  with no params, it asks for current password, and then prompts `Bad: new password is too simple`

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04! (Kinda surprised since it's been 8 years since the answer.)

Comment: Even though there is an error for palindrome passwords, the change is applied after repeating the password.

Comment: Does not work in **Ubuntu >= 22**, as (1) the length is defined in `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` and (2) the minimum length configurable is **6** - not lower.

Answer (score 44):

By default, Ubuntu requires a minimum password length of 6 characters, as well as some basic entropy checks. These values are controlled in the file **/etc/pam.d/common-password**, which is outlined below.

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

If you would like to adjust the minimum length to 4 characters, add the appropriate variable (**minlen=4**) to the end of the line. The modification is outlined below.

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=4
```

[Source.](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/user-management.html)

Comment: I couldn't get min= to work and it doesn't match the man page, despite the Wiki page. Seems to be minlen=

Comment: remove "obscure" for also disable complexity check

Comment: `sudo passwd user` seems more useful

Answer (score 30):

Bring up a terminal and edit /etc/pam.d/common-password

Change this line:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

to:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=4
```

Password also need a certain amount of complexity, as specified by the obscure parameter above.

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=2 sha512
```

removes that check also.

This all presupposes that you think this is wise.

See `man pam_unix`

These work on my system.

Comment: this works for ubuntu12.04

Comment: valid for 13.04 too

Comment: valid for 15.10 (Wily), too.

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04 none of other solutions worked for me. I had to replace both of these lines:

```
password    requisite                   pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3 dcredit=-1 enforce_for_root lcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 reject_username ucredit=-1
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
```

in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` with:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=2 sha512
```

These changes let me changed my password easily and after changing password I restored file to it's original form.

Answer (score 4):

To set up a simple password, I tried the simple `sudo passwd username` method, but it failed on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

So I tried to remove the `obscure` option from `/etc/pam.d/common-passwd` config file, but it still failed.

So I also removed the `obscure` option from `/usr/share/pam-configs/unix` config file. And then it worked :-)

I do agree that it should be simplier, when acting as `su` to set up a weak password, whatever the reason why one wants to do it! A warning saying "weak password, confirm?" would be perfect...

Comment: Narrow minded people have given negative votes on this excellent answer. The reference to "obscure" in /usr/share/pam-configs/unix is very important and relevant to some situations. Just because it doesn't work for you doesn't mean it's not a good answer. Lighten up on the negative votes guys and welcome someone with a viewpoint that's different than yours! You might be better informed at the end of the day.

Comment: In support of user171987's answer read the page at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec#config_file_format . It shows how the PAM configuration works and explains the profiles and their usage. The folder pam-configs holds various configurations and "unix" is just one of them.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, it looks like it's sufficient to simply remove the 'obscure' option from /etc/pam.d/common-passwd  -- there's no need to overly complicate things by also editing /usr/share/pam-configs/unix

Comment: Worked for me in 20.04 Server, thank you. I removed `obscure` and added `minlen=1`, both actions were required.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with PAM pwdfile module.

The way described here changes only the desktop login (lightdm service), but can be applied to other services as well if you wish.

Also, this allows you to have your original strong password for "sudo", while maintaining a fairly easy way to login to Ubuntu desktop.

Commands can be issued in the terminal program.

### Installing the software

First, we install a software package named `libpam-pwdfile`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-pwdfile
```

### Creating the user-password file

We will then create the user/password file. You will be prompted to enter a new PIN password. Your password will be encrypted and saved to a file named `passwd.like`

```
pinpass=$(mkpasswd -5)
echo "$pinpass" | sudo tee /etc/passwd.like
```

*Alternatively*, you may use: `openssl passwd -1 yourpinpasswordhere` and create a file named /etc/passwd.like and that password.

### Setting up the desktop login service

The next step is to prepare the desktop login service to accept the PIN password before other password procedures. I've mentioned already the name of the *desktop login service*, `lightdm`.

Take a look at the file:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

If you don't have this file, then your desktop (login) service is a *different* one, and you should find your desktop manager before going further. As explained before, this guide is for Ubuntu 16.04 but can be used for other login services as well.

It could be useful if you also create a backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/pam.d/lightdm /etc/pam.d/lightdm.backup
```

Now, you may edit the file using nano or gedit or any other text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/lightdm
```

At the top of the file mine had:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
```

I have modified it like so:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth requisite pam_nologin.so
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile=/etc/passwd.like
auth required pam_permit.so
#@include common-auth
```

Save the file and close your text editor.

Log out and log back in.

You should be able to use the PIN password you set. By following this guide, the PIN password is only used for the desktop login service, not for the password of sudo commands.

Source: http://blog.radevic.com/2017/11/how-to-set-pin-password-or-short.html

Comment: interesting stuff. Can you please look at the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001987/altering-authentication-process-to-incorporate-pin-features) that I just posted right after your answer, accidentally? Thanks.