# Why does Ubuntu 12.04 have more stringent complexity requirements, and how to to remove them?

Tags: 12.04, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a short password on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180402/how-to-set-a-short-password-on-ubuntu)

I was wondering why the developers of Ubuntu made stricter conditions for user passwords than before? My password has to contain letters and numbers, has to be minimum this length, maximum that length. It's quite annoying. And is there any way to bypass these requirements and set my user password to something easy such as 'foobar' ?

I'm sorry if this question was already answered but I couldn't find a specific solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Ubuntu developers probably have a legit reason but I was able to change my password to something short and easy now, while keeping in mind that it could be harmful. That's all I really needed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you got your question answered. Since the [linked question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180402/how-to-set-a-short-password-on-ubuntu) fully met your needs, we'll probably close this as a duplicate of that. ([kamil's answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/197094/22949) could then be merged into that question.)

Answer (score 3):

### To decrease the minimum password length:

1. Open the `/etc/login.defs` file in your preferred text editor as a root user.
2. Change the `PASS_MIN_LEN` variable to the minimum number of characters for the password.
3. Save and close the `/etc/login.defs` file.

Comment: The root user can also override the password complexity requirements. If security is not an issue, then you can just try `sudo passwd $USER` to set a short password.