# How do I bypass the "Password needs to be longer" warning while setting a new password?

Tags: password, security, authentication

I want to have a password Ubuntu but is says it's too easy to guess

[image: Warning while setting new password]

Can I bypass this?

Comment: The last I knew, [these directions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/06/minimum-password-length-ubuntu/) were still valid.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328997/simple-password-problem) as well.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: This one I mean https://askubuntu.com/questions/328997/simple-password-problem

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. This should probably be flagged as a duplicate, but it has another answer and I'm not sure what the protocol is in those situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set long throwaway password and then type this in terminal to change it to shorter one `sudo passwd <user>`
It should allow short password this way