# Login Screen -- Do not hit enter key

Tags: login, login-screen

Is there a method that will login me in withouit having to hit the "enter" key? In Winows 10, one simple enters the correct PW and is immediately taken to the desktop...no need to hit "enter."

Comment: In Windows 10 that would be the PIN that is accepted without the Enter key, not the password.  To setup the PIN authentication see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1001983/231142  But I am not aware of anything in Ubuntu at the moment that will allow for PIN without pressing the Enter key.