# How to make Ubuntu immediately login when I finish entering my password, without hitting enter key. Like in Windows 10

Tags: login

A tiny feature that I liked in Windows 10 was that as soon as I finish entering my login pin the computer logs you in, you don't have to hit the enter key to login, it's a tiny convenience but something I miss after switching from Windows. Since Linux is known for its customization, I was wondering if something similar can be implemented in Ubuntu. My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Please see:  https://askubuntu.com/q/1071489/231142

Answer (score 0):

The password will always require <kbd>enter</kbd> because only then will the OS check your entry against the stored hash (This is in my experience the same in Windows).

What you can do in Windows is to assign a PIN (I fail to see why this might be useful, but we are not talking Windows here :-))

Comment: Okay so can I assign a pin to ubuntu in place of a password, such that as soon as I enter the pin it logs me in without having to hit the enter key