# Set short password Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I can't set a short password in the user change password.

Additionally, I tried implementing the solutions of [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180402/how-to-set-a-short-password-on-ubuntu), but none of them worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Run `sudo passwd <your-username>` from the terminal. When run by root (`sudo`), `passwd` program should ignore all password policies set in PAM configuration. It will complain that the password does not meet the requirements, but will set it anyway.

Comment: This method may get conflict with the Desktop - GUI login.

Comment: Why? If you set password via `passwd`, GUI login will just use it.

Comment: Thanks for adding that it may complain but will set it anyway. It seemed to me that "BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters" means it's rejected.

Answer (score 2):

```
root@dlp:~# vi /etc/security/pwquality.conf
# line 11 : uncomment and set minimum length (example below means 8 char)

minlen = 8
```

source: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=pam&f=1

Comment: **Note:** In Ubuntu >= 22.X this value cannot be set to a value lower than **6**.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't set a short password in the user change password.

Correct. It follows the "password policy" set for all Linux systems:

> By default, all Linux operating systems requires password length of minimum 6 characters for the users.

If you really want to change it use this:

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

and find this line:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure yescrypt
```

and add `minlen=N` where N is the minimal length you want it to be. Default is 6.

If all you want is to change the password to a short one please do stay away from editing it. It is easier to just use command line for this. It needs to be like this to bypass password policies:

```
sudo passwd $USER
```

Plain `passwd` will also complain about the length (it uses the same setting as above)

Comment: I changed the  **/etc/pam.d/common-password** based on your answer, but I can't set short password in User settings yet :(